# Some dbo.aspnet_something in database purpose

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, database-design

I saw some social networking like sites applications database listed on

dbo.aspnet_profile
dbo.aspnet_roles ect..

folders.Is this a default membership or What you guys call this  ? Is this call a memership provider ?

Here i have attached image for more illustration

[image]

Is thisone available in .NET Framework 4.0 ?

Comment: Yes those are the tables that asp.net uses for Membership Provider. To manage user-based web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called ASP.net membership.

ASP.net Membership was released in .net 2.0 but is still current and can be used with .net 4.0.

You can install it very easily. [Instructions](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx)

You will need to understand how the database is designed. [Relational Diagram](http://leonardwoody.com/2010/06/02/asp-net-membership-entity-relatioship-diagram/)

Finally here is a good instruction [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxxFhGF-Z7E).